# Asp.Net Core MVC 7 C# - Recommended approach of passing data to and from controller from a page that has multiple forms and states

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a simple web portal using the .Net Core 7 MVC template in VS2022 (It's challenging to know if this is the latest recommended format and or template, Microsoft doesn't really state what is the current approach from a stack perspective).

As part of building out and focusing on MVC I looked at if `PageModels` were the recommended method of binding to the page or if using a simple Model and populating the page using razor syntax (Which is my preference) was the most modern recommendation (Again Microsoft documentation isn't exactly specific).

That aside, the specific problem that I have is that I'm building out a settings page that has a number of different forms and I initially thought that in order to maintain the page state of other inputs and fields that when a form posts to the controller it sends the entire page model with the form bound properties populated, perform some logic, and pass a modified model back the the main Index `ActionMethod`. However I can't seem to see anything specific around sending the entire model back that was used by the razor page as part of individual form submits. Or moreover, if it's even a good idea.

The page structure looks like this.

- Form - Team Name
- Button - Submit, just saves the team name.
- List - Team Members currently in team.
- Form - Search for Users by Email.
- List - List of Users matching Search input, with button to `Add To Team`

The issue i have is that if I pass back the form properties which are bound to the model from the search input, i don't get all of the other model properties used for populating current team members list, or the team name, so I assume that would mean that the controller has to do the work of getting that data again? This seems a bit inefficient in my mind. I'm assuming there is a clever way of doing this and achieving an appropriate outcome but I'm struggling to see the light through the dark with this particular consideration. Any suggestions or nods in the right direction are appreciated.

**Example Model**

```
public class SettingsPageModel
{
    public SettingsPageModel() { }

    public SettingsPageModel(string teamName)
    {
        TeamName = teamName;
    }

    public SettingsPageModel(SearchModel searchModel)
    {
        SearchModel = searchModel;
    }

    public SettingsPageModel(string teamName, List<TeamMember> teamMembers, SearchModel searchModel)
    {
        TeamName = teamName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(teamName));
        TeamMembers = teamMembers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(teamMembers));
        SearchModel = searchModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchModel));
    }

    public string TeamName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; } = new();
    public SearchModel SearchModel { get; set; } = new();
    public DialogModel? DialogModel { get; set; }
}

public class SearchModel
{
    public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public List<User>? SearchedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about just using a single page with [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for each of the settings categories?  That would only require a single page model.

Comment: I did notice that I can use 'return PartialView()' in the controller action methods, but I'm not sure what that does, is it similar to a partial post back that we could do in Ajax's update panels back in the day?

Comment: I had in mind simply updating the whole model.  In this context the partials are just a way to encapsulate the markup for each settings category.

Comment: If you want to get all the properties in your view, You need to create a ViewModel to contains all the properties in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you submit a form you send back ONLY the input elements on that form (not the entire model).

If you have a search input and want to update only a portion of the page you would have to either:

- Add more hidden input fields to that form to send for example TeamName and populate the model completely (not ideal)
- Use Ajax when the form is submitted, have an Action in your controller that gets the filtered users and return a PartialView() with the list of users, and update the DOM using JavaScript when you get your ajax response (HTML)